# Issue in decoding filename with charset iso-2022-jp from Mime header based on rfc 2231

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime

In javamail i set mail.mime.decodeparameter as true. I have the Mimeheader for the attachment as below.

```
Content-Type: image/png;
 name*0*=ISO-2022-JP''%1B%24B%24%22%24%24%24%26%24%28%24*%24%22%24%24%24%26;
 name*1*=%24%28%24*%24%22%24%24%24%26%24%28%24*%24%22%24%24%24%26%24%28;
 name*2*=%24*%1B%28B.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;
 filename*0*=ISO-2022-JP''%1B%24B%24%22%24%24%24%26%24%28%24*%24%22%24%24;
 filename*1*=%24%26%24%28%24*%24%22%24%24%24%26%24%28%24*%24%22%24%24%24;
 filename*2*=%26%24%28%24*%1B%28B.png
```

While getting filename using part.getFileName(), the filename not rendered properly. The filename has been rendered as below.

```
あいうえおあいう$&$($*$"$$$&$($*$"$$$&$($*.png
```

But the actual filename is あいうえおあいうえおあいうえおあいうえお.png .

When i debug the source of javamail, in the ParameterList.java in the decodeBytes() method return corrupted string for the value pf continuation parameters, when the encoded string are split. I think when double bytes charset such as iso-2022-jp are splitted it returns corrupted string in javamail. Whether Am I correct?
Or please suggest me workaround to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not really clear in the [RFC 2231 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231), because each section of the parameter can control whether that section is encoded or not, it implies that the encoding of each section is independent of the encoding of other sections, and thus that sections can be decoded independently.  After checking with the author of the spec, I've determined that that's not necessarily true.  Thus, this looks like a bug in JavaMail.  The fix looks non-trivial.